# Is there are a way to do Dependency injection inside ObjectGraphType

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql

I am doing a simple tutorial for GraphQL.
Many old examples are confusing or don't work with .NET 5 and newest Nuget package. I am building GraphQL application and there is a tutorial where this code works :

```
public DragonType(DragonExpertOpinionRepository rep)
{
    Field<ListGraphType<DragonOpinionType>>("opinions",
        resolve: context => rep.GetForDragonId(context.Source.Id));
    
    Field(t => t.Id);
```

The problem is this constructor. I have no idea how I can resolve this. I tried some magic with "IServiceProvider" but this also isn't resolved. How GrapQL can know how to inject "DragonExpertOpinionRepository"?

This is my code in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDragonPersitence(Configuration);


    services.AddScoped<DragonType>(sp =>
    {
        return new DragonType(sp.GetRequiredService<DragonExpertOpinionRepository>());
    });

    services.AddScoped<DragonSchema>();

    services.AddGraphQL(o => { })
     .AddGraphTypes(ServiceLifetime.Scoped)
     .AddNewtonsoftJson();

    // If using Kestrel:
    services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    });

    // If using IIS:
    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    });
}
```

DragonSchema :

```
public class DragonSchema : Schema
{
    private readonly DragonShopDbContext _dbContext;

    public DragonSchema(DragonShopDbContext dbContext) : base()
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;

        Query = new DragonQuery
           (new DragonRepository(_dbContext));
    }
}
```

And DragonQuery :

```
public class DragonQuery : ObjectGraphType
{
    public DragonQuery(DragonRepository productRepository)
    {  
        Field<ListGraphType<DragonType>>(
            "dragons",
            resolve: context => productRepository.GetAll()

        );
    }
}
```

I am accepting simple answer : "WTF are doing". Tutorial that is doing this is wrong.
You can Injecting stuff only in GraphQL Schema.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add IServiceProvider to constructor injection in schema. Everything works after I added this :

```
public class DragonSchema : Schema
{
    private readonly DragonShopDbContext _dbContext;

    public DragonSchema(DragonShopDbContext dbContext, IServiceProvider sp) : base(sp)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;

        Query = new DragonQuery
           (new DragonRepository(_dbContext));
    }
}
```

Then you can inject anything in "ObjectGraphType" classes